# Debugging javascript: Why having Chrome performance tools on makes the page faster?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a web components library and I get a slowness problem on my tables (grid) that I am trying to debug.

When I test my page, the 500 rows table construction takes 11 seconds. Now if I launch Devtools Performance tools, and I reload my table, it takes only 2 seconds. And that's every time: 11 seconds without Performance analysis, and 2 seconds if it's running.

How come?

The same thing takes 0.5 sec with Firefox, with or without perf analysis.

I can set up an example online if anyone is interested to look into it...

Thanks

Comment: Did you check **why** it takes 11 seconds? Is this a networking issue?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not a networking issue, and I was using the performance tool to try to find out why :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately performance benchmarking isn't a definite stable thing. For example one piece of code could show different performance based on which code was executed before it. Sometimes a code could use some optimizations done by a JS engine before by executing completely different code. So I'm afraid the performance tool pushed the JS engine to optimize some pieces that was used on the code being benchmarked later. To analyze a code it should be ran alone on a page for ideal results.

As an example take 2 benchmarks.

As you see in the following results in Chrome `Nina's solution` performs faster together with `Nina's reviver suggestion`. To avoid this we need to execute each solution on a clean page, which will be the next version of my benchmark tool. Firefox gives stable results.

```
` Chrome/117
----------------------------------------------------------------
Nina's solution             1.0x  |  x1  115  125  126  146  173
Alexander's solution        1.3x  |  x1  150  152  154  162  169
Nina's reviver suggestion   5.8x  |  x1  670  678  679  700  739
----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/118
----------------------------------------------------------------
Nina's solution             1.0x  |  x1   83   84   86  108  115
Nina's reviver suggestion   1.8x  |  x1  150  151  156  164  188
Alexander's solution        2.2x  |  x1  181  182  195  206  261
----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const chunk = [
    { "x": "1", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "2", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "3", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "4", "y": "25" },
    { "x": "5", "y": "45" },
    { "x": "6", "y": "49" }
];

let aa = [];

let count = 100009;
while (count--) {
    aa.push(...chunk);
}

aa = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aa));

// @benchmark Nina's solution
aa.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, +v])));

// @benchmark Nina's reviver suggestion
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aa), (k, v) => typeof v === 'string' ? +v : v);

// @benchmark Alexander's solution
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aa).replace(/"(\d+)"/g, '$1'));

const CYCLES = 1;
/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

```
` Chrome/117
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander's solution   1.0x  |  x1  141  152  157  159  168
Nina's solution        1.0x  |  x1  147  154  163  167  169
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/118
-----------------------------------------------------------
Nina's solution        1.0x  |  x1   88   88   88   98  130
Alexander's solution   2.1x  |  x1  181  185  190  204  216
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const chunk = [
    { "x": "1", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "2", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "3", "y": "12" },
    { "x": "4", "y": "25" },
    { "x": "5", "y": "45" },
    { "x": "6", "y": "49" }
];

let aa = [];

let count = 100009;
while (count--) {
    aa.push(...chunk);
}

aa = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aa));

// @benchmark Nina's solution
aa.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, +v])));

// @benchmark Alexander's solution
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aa).replace(/"(\d+)"/g, '$1'));

const CYCLES = 1;
/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```