# Find the highest number with same key from a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
data = {
  "lists": {
    "list-1": {
      "id": "list-1",
      "title": "list1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    },
    "list-2": {
      "id": "list-2",
      "title": "list2",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to find the highest item with "id" as key. So here it would be "20"

I know how to do within an array but not from a multi dimensional array like here

```
const list = data.lists[listId]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const entryWithHighestID = 
  Object.entries(data.lists)          // from all the entries of data.lists
    .map(([key, { cards }]) => cards) // extract the cards property
    .flat()                           // flat to a single array
    .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)[0];  // sort by id descending, and get the first entry
```

Comment: here's a minor issue with the sorting logic. You are sorting the cards in descending order of their "id" values, but the comparison function should be a.id - b.id instead of b.id - a.id to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: a very inefficient solution

Comment: @BGPHiJACK OP wants the highest ID, not the lowest.

Comment: That is understood. Try some testing.

Comment: What's to test? OP wants the entry with id:20, and this code returns it, try it for yourself

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the lists to a min value of card ids:

```js
const max = Object.keys(data.lists).reduce((r, key) => data.lists[key].cards.forEach(card => +card.id > r.id && (r = card)) || r, {id: -1});
console.log(max);
```

```html
<script>
const data={lists:{"list-1":{id:"list-1",title:"list1",cards:[{id:"20",title:"title"},{id:"2",title:"title"}]},"list-2":{id:"list-2",title:"list2",cards:[{id:"4",title:"title"},{id:"3",title:"title"}]}}};
</script>
```

If you want the maximum speed, just loop:

```js
let max = {id: -1};

for(const key in data.lists){
  const cards = data.lists[key].cards;
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    const card = cards[i];
    if(+card.id > max.id) max = card;
  }
}
console.log(max);
```

```html
<script>
const data={lists:{"list-1":{id:"list-1",title:"list1",cards:[{id:"20",title:"title"},{id:"2",title:"title"}]},"list-2":{id:"list-2",title:"list2",cards:[{id:"4",title:"title"},{id:"3",title:"title"}]}}};
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/117
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander fast looping           1.0x  |  x10000000  334  343  344  345  358
pilchard's tweak to one-liner    1.2x  |  x10000000  397  400  405  407  410
Alexander one-liner              1.3x  |  x10000000  424  427  429  429  432
moonwave99                      15.3x  |   x1000000  512  512  513  519  521
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const data={lists:{"list-1":{id:"list-1",title:"list1",cards:[{id:"20",title:"title"},{id:"2",title:"title"}]},"list-2":{id:"list-2",title:"list2",cards:[{id:"4",title:"title"},{id:"3",title:"title"}]}}};

// @benchmark moonwave99
Object.entries(data.lists)         // from all the entries of data.lists
    .map(([key, { cards }]) => cards) // extract the cards property
    .flat()                           // flat to a single array
    .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)[0];

// @benchmark pilchard's tweak to one-liner
Object.keys(data.lists).reduce((r, key) => data.lists[key].cards.reduce((c, card) => +card.id > c.id ? card : c, r), {id: -1});

// @benchmark Alexander one-liner
Object.keys(data.lists).reduce((r, key) => data.lists[key].cards.forEach(card => +card.id > r.id && (r = card)) || r, {id: -1});

// @benchmark Alexander fast looping
let max = {id: -1};

for(const key in data.lists){
  const cards = data.lists[key].cards;
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
    const card = cards[i];
    if(+card.id > max.id) max = card;
  }
}
max;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: the forEach method does not return a value that can be used to update r correctly.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK look closer, the code works fine

Comment: Your fast looping method if it works as intended, the tests showed it to be 1.8M OP/s good job. it's slightly faster than your proposed method but massive gains there, low complexity smart.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK what do you use to test it?

Comment: Simple stuff, https://jsbench.me/. I run each test and it runs samples. 
I was curious, looking at your example, should it not be +cards[i].id; instead of +id?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK i'm working on my benchmark tool that could be embedded here. Some problems could be with jsbench.me and other benchmark sites. The less code is on the page is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207101/debugging-javascript-why-having-chrome-performance-tools-on-makes-the-page-fast/77207390#77207390. But seems the results very similar between my benchmark and jsbench.me

Comment: Oh added bonus, I like to use https://jshint.com/ to make sure I'm not making ES6 errors naturally and keeping complexity low. Consider jsbench a bit more thorough your tests were almost 18x faster haha.

Comment: You can replace the awkward `forEach` in your one-liner with a nested reduce `Object.keys(data.lists).reduce((r, key) => data.lists[key].cards.reduce((c, card) => +card.id > c.id ? card : c, r), {id: -1});` which also seems to be faster in your benchmark.

Comment: @pilchard, even performs better, updated the benchmark

Comment: @BGPHiJACK checked jsbench.me, it s*cks...

Comment: interesting tool you have created

Comment: @cmgchess you are welcome to use, any questions leave as an issue here: https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark

Answer (score 0):

You can find the highest item with the "id" key from the given multidimensional array by iterating through the nested structures and keeping track of the highest value found. Here's a JavaScript function that accomplishes this:

Most Efficient method: 120OP/s

```js
const data = {
  "lists": {
    "list-1": {
      "id": "list-1",
      "title": "list1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    },
    "list-2": {
      "id": "list-2",
      "title": "list2",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
function findHighestId(data) {
  let highestId = -1;

  for (const listKey in data.lists) {
    const list = data.lists[listKey];

    for (const card of list.cards) {
      const cardId = parseInt(card.id, 10);

      if (!isNaN(cardId) && cardId > highestId) {
        highestId = cardId;
      }
    }
  }

  return highestId;
}

const highestId = findHighestId(data);
console.log("Highest ID:", highestId); // Output: Highest ID: 20
```

Another way to write it: 86K OP/s

```js
const data = {
  "lists": {
    "list-1": {
      "id": "list-1",
      "title": "list1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    },
    "list-2": {
      "id": "list-2",
      "title": "list2",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

function findHighestId(data) {
  return Object.values(data.lists)
    .flatMap(list => list.cards)
    .map(card => parseInt(card.id))
    .filter(id => !isNaN(id))
    .reduce((highestId, currentId) => Math.max(highestId, currentId), -1);
}

const highestId = findHighestId(data);
console.log("Highest ID:", highestId); // Output: Highest ID: 20
```

One last attempt... this can be done many ways: 86K OP/s

```js
const data = {
  "lists": {
    "list-1": {
      "id": "list-1",
      "title": "list1",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "20",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    },
    "list-2": {
      "id": "list-2",
      "title": "list2",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "title": "title"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "title": "title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};


const highestId = Object.values(data.lists)
  .flatMap(list => list.cards)
  .reduce((highest, card) => {
    const cardId = parseInt(card.id);
    return cardId > highest ? cardId : highest;
  }, -1);

console.log("Highest ID:", highestId);
```

Comment: using Object.values & flatMap is the slowest option, check my benchmark

Comment: Yeah sadly it's engine specific on performance, I would use the initial looping mechanism provided or make changes to how the data is stored/presented.

Comment: I'll update my result because the first response I made is fastest at 120KOP/s the other two tie at 86K OP/s. Checking your fast looping you'd have the fastest statement by far.

Comment: it's not engine specific, the same tendency in FF, it's bad logic of creating intermediate throw-away arrays

Comment: Oh, FF is not a fare assessment, it uses V8 still; Apple is on that fancy stuff. But your code does look fast bravo.

Comment: i believe FF has been always using own engine (Gecko, Quantum, and SpiderMonkey; WebKit on iOS) , benchmarks are very different from V8/Blink/Chromium based browsers.

Comment: Not for JavaScript, for HTML/CSS sure. The may make their own adjustments to the engine/addons but yeah some engines are killing it with javascript. I believe they use SpiderMonkey but it has many of V8 features/code in there. It's a continuous growth.

Comment: Many of the engines base off V8 with some added touches, very few are full revamps but not impossible FF is getting there they do a lot of things chrome isn't doing right now and the same goes for all browsers in their lane. Apple is on another level however with their Nitro stuff, they don't want to follow people but it could be cool.

Comment: btw moonwave99 was right, we should return an object with max id, not max id itself... that's why his answer was accepted despite of logic with poor performance

Comment: Yes you'd be right, however some fine display of options tonight. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = { "lists": { 
    "list-1": { "id": "list-1", "title": "list1",
      "cards": [ { "id": "20", "title": "title" },
                 { "id":  "2", "title": "title" } ] },
    "list-2": { "id": "list-2", "title": "list2",
      "cards": [ { "id": "4", "title": "title" },
                 { "id": "3", "title": "title" } ] } } }

const max = Object.values(data.lists)
                  .flatMap(o => o.cards)
                  .sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)[0]

console.log( max )
```